# Access Private Google drive doc without port 8080

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am trying to Access Private google drive docs using python and the Google api however I am coming against a major issue due to IT security restraints

I can't use any Port (e.g 8080) to oauth my app, as IT, have blocked localhost from  being used is there anyway you can access Drive Docs with an old fashioned key? or another method of authentication.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, for example, how about using Service Account for your situation? When the Service Account is used, the authorization process using the browser is not required. By this, it is not required to use localhost as the redirect uri. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.